# Rails won't take my authentication token with Net::HTTP::Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote a script to send a `GET` request to my Rails server so I could retrieve the authentication token from a form and then do a `POST` request right afterwards that uses that token.

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'

    uri = URI 'http://localhost:4321/'
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.path, "ACCEPT" => "text/html"
    response = http.request request

    token = response.body.split('<meta name="csrf-token" content="')[1].split('"')[0]

    p token

    sleep(3)

    form_data = {
        "utf8" => "\u2713",
        "authenticity_token" => token, 
        "commit" => "Create my account", 
        "controller" => "users", 
        "action" => "create"
    }

    uri = URI "http://localhost:4321/users"
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path, "ACCEPT" => "text/html"
    request.set_form_data form_data
    response = http.request(request)
```

My server keeps rejecting the token:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

The token's encoding looks fine in the console on both ends. Also, in the Rails console, the `params` hash from my script looks just like the `params` hash when I use a browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the csrf token needs to match the token in the session.  If you're not including a session, it may be generating a new token with each request

Comment: It works through the browser every time: I load the page with the form and hit the form's submit button. The server then verifies the token. I haven't set up anything with sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! The missing component was the session cookie. When you `GET` a page from Rails, it sends a `_yourappnamehere_session=somereallylongID` string with the key `SET-COOKIE` in the response headers. Here's one that it gave me:

```
_sample_app_session=NFY1TkVzd3lhWnhRVVlhMEovcnZZWm13T0JVYXNQQitRS0hzRVJvcmVzSjgyeHlKUnE4Wmxrc1paVnhuUGY3K3VLbXdIOThBUjlSM2cyZU1CbnJEVGdvcTRIMEZ1b3d6eEp4QmpVNFowL3ZBMnl6Q0pqU2xzUTZjdzRhVGZSK3FTT00yN3dORktEc0FuZWFkY3B3d3N3PT0tLVlaZWNidnZQRmNOK2wwYWZhTWVBQnc9PQ%3D%3D--d623ac034f5b15a64f975b9cd87be943f42f3cfc
```

You need to store this string when it comes in the response headers from your `GET` request for the page with the form. When you send the `POST` request, include that string under the key `COOKIE` in your request headers. Of course, you still need to send the `authenticity_token` in your `POST` data.

Here's my final working code:

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'

    uri = URI 'http://localhost:4321/signup'
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.path
    response = http.request request

    token = response.body.split('<meta name="csrf-token" content="')[1].split('"')[0]

    cookie = response.get_fields('set-cookie')[1].split(";")[0]


    form_data = {
        "authenticity_token" => token
    }

    uri = URI "http://localhost:4321/users"
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path, "COOKIE" => cookie
    request.set_form_data form_data
    response = http.request request

    p response.body
```

I should note that I took the `utf8` key out of the `form_data` and the only header I sent is the `COOKIE` header. The `utf8` key and some other headers probably help with encoding and some other stuff, but here I was just trying to see the minimum requirements for getting my token authenticated.

Swards, you were on the right track, and Wand Maker, I found my answer by digging around in the network messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `token` value in HTTP header `X-CSRF-Token`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Here's my latest request: 

`request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path, "ACCEPT" => "text/html",
                    "REFERER" => "http://localhost:4321/signup",
                    "ORIGIN" => "http://localhost:4321",
                    "CONNECTION" => "keep-alive",
                    "CACHE_CONTROL" => "max-age=0",
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN" => token`

I tried to make the headers match the browser-given headers (which actually don't have `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in them) as much as possible, because it authenticates the token from the browser requests.

Comment: You say it works from browser.  Can you use developer tools (F12 button in Chrome) and watch HTTP network messages and see how token is getting sent from browser to server?  You will have to mimic the same behavior.